# Uploading existing videos from iOS to SF1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, chatter, ios

We are implementing a custom chatter component(lightning), where in we **need to post a chatter(including files up to 25 MB at least, up to 2GB) from Desktop, an Android device, and an iOS device.**

We are using ForceTK to upload files. We are able to upload all types of files and post a chatter including them.

**But only and only are unable to upload an existing video file(any type of video file), from an iOS device.** We are able to upload videos taken at the time of upload, just not ones from the device's photo library. We are not seeing this issue on Android devices or on the desktop.

It would be very helpful if anyone can help us out here, or suggest a method which they had used in case they faced a similar issue earlier.

Thanks a lot!